# Angular, File Upload

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm Having a problem with an file upload:
html:

```
 <form #cv="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(cv.value)" (ngSubmit)="onUpload" class="form">
            <div ngModelGroup="curriculum" #curriculum="ngModelGroup">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Allega</label>
                    <div *ngIf="uploadResponse.status === 'error'">
                        {{ uploadResponse.message }}
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="uploadResponse.status === 'progress'">
                        <div role="progressbar" [style.width.%]="uploadResponse.message" aria-valuenow="25"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                            {{uploadResponse.message}}%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input ngModel type="file" name="upload" id="customFile" #curriculum1="ngModel" exportParts
                        (change)="onFileChange($event)" class="custom-file-input" (change)="log(curriculum)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx">
                </div>
```

upload.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse,HttpClientModule, HttpEventType } from  '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from  'rxjs/operators';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {
  SERVER_URL: string = "http://localhost:4200";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  
  public upload(data, userId) {
    let uploadURL = `${this.SERVER_URL}/auth/${userId}/avatar`;

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(uploadURL, data, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    }).pipe(map((event) => {

      switch (event.type) {

        case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
          const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
          return { status: 'progress', message: progress };

        case HttpEventType.Response:
          return event.body;
        default:
          return `Unhandled event: ${event.type}`;
      }
    })
    );
  }
}
```

first-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpEventType, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { UploadService } from  '../upload.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'first-page',
  templateUrl: './first-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-page.component.css']
})
export class FirstPageComponent implements OnInit  {
  conoscenze:string[]=[];
  upload: any;
  appCfg: any;
  log(x){console.log(x);}
  submit(f){console.log(f);}

  
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private uploadService: UploadService)
 {
   this.form=this.formBuilder.group({
     upload:[this.upload]
   });
 }

form: FormGroup;
  error: string;
  userId: number = 1;
  uploadResponse = { status: '', message: '', filePath: '' };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      avatar: ['']
    });
  }

  onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.form.get('upload').setValue(file);
    }
  }

  onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.form.get('upload').value);

    this.uploadService.upload(formData, this.userId).subscribe(
      (res) => this.uploadResponse = res,
      (err) => this.error = err
    );
  }
}
```

my purpose is to upload a file .pdf or .docx but actually i can't answer myself why it doesn't work :( .
actually i think i made all the imports(also in app.module.ts).
there is way more code but it's for other parts of the form that actually work.

the Error in the console is :
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of null

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am missing something here. But you seem to be overwriting the form that you created in the constructor in the ngOnInit. Once it comes to ngOnInit, there is no form control called "upload" in the formgroup. Hence when you try to do setValue in the onFileChange method, it fails

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, private uploadService: UploadService)
 {
   this.form=this.formBuilder.group({
     upload:[this.upload]
   });
 }

form: FormGroup;
  error: string;
  userId: number = 1;
  uploadResponse = { status: '', message: '', filePath: '' };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      avatar: ['']
    });
  }
```

Comment: and what are u proposing me to do? Thanks for the comment

Comment: Why do you need to reinitialize the form group in the ngonInit. Ideally, the code that you have in the constructor should be in the ngOnInit. I dont see you using the avatar form control anywhere. So unless you have not posted the full code, I would remove the code in the ngOnInit and move the code in the constructor to the ngOnInit

Comment: Ok!! If it worked, please mark the solution as the correct answer!! Thanks!!